# split multi-valued list and fill down

Tags: python, python-2.7

My original data are from Twitter. It looks like this in csv:

```
@kevin, There's an important connection
@kevin, @EnvDefenseFund Launch Pad For Energy Innovations
@kevin, RT @HenriVerdier: hello @LesEchos
@chris, you're great @kevin
```

I am trying to extract usernames from the data using the following codes (there may be a better way of doing this):

```
for tweet in tweets:
    print tweet[0], re.findall(r"(?<=@)\w+", str(tweet[1]))
```

The results look like this:

```
@kevin []
@kevin ['EnvDefenseFund']
@kevin ['HenriVerdier', 'LesEchos']
@chris ['kevin']
```

Ultimately, I would like to have the data in the following format:

```
@kevin,
@kevin, @EnvDefenseFund
@kevin, @HenriVerdier
@kevin, @LesEchos    
@chris, @kevin
```

That way, I can see the relationships among people.

Comment: Your data does not like any python list , is that from some file or so? Also have you tried anything for this?

Comment: @AnandSKumar I think that it's not a list, just some data.

Comment: what do you mean by some data? Is that raw text?

Comment: Why is the ouputs as list, when it would only contain at most one item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need something like this:

```
for tweet in tweets:
    a = re.findall(r"(?<=@)\w+", str(tweet[1]))
    for i in a:
        print tweet[0]+',', '@'+i
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion!